# WordPress Gravity Forms Field Entry

Tags: wordpress, missing-data, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a WordPress site running gravity forms, I need a lot of info on my visitors, they are good at responding but I have one field (it's mandatory) that somehow skips the mandatory part. So out of 200 entries only 2 has answered that question.

I can't seem to find the solution – since the field is mandatory, they should not be able to leave the field blank.

What to do?

Comment: You may want to try asking this over on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GoBusto but WordPress.SE is really for [help with WordPress theme and plugin development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), not plugin support, and they've specifically stated Gravity Forms support is off-topic on the [tag wiki](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-gravity-forms).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using conditional logic on the Submit button and that field, where the submit button won't show up until they have filled in that field?